# Using carriewave-vips with 16-bit tiff

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, carrierwave, vips

I'm using carrierwave-vips (with ruby-vips) to upload and process 16 bit tiff. The 16 bit tiff will get save (not a problem for carrierewave alone), but I also want to process a thumbnail (jpeg). The problem is that the resulting thumbnail is completely blown out. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the 16 bit digtals that represents your band levels aren't getting scaled down. Add the following method to your uploader:

```
def convert_to_8bit
    manipulate! do |image|
      #vips specific
      image.scale
    end
  end
```

and then `process: :convert_to_8bit` in your version.

Comment: `image.scale` will search the image for max and min, then scale it to fit 0 - 255. This will produce bad results for some images. You want to just take the top 8 bits of the 16. I would use `(image >> 8).clip2fmt :uchar`, ie. shift bits 8 to the right, cast down to unsigned char. The most recent libvips, 7.32, will do this for you automatically, so updating is also an option.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. Probably not a big use issue for my current image set, but very relevant. I'll try to upgrade my libvips first and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I've upgraded to 7.32 and it doesn't seem to be doing this automatically. I believe you are a maintainer, should I open up a bug? The file that I'm using is a ~200mb grayscale 16 tiff.